# New Universality Classes and Multiple Transition Points in Systems

Tags: statistical-mechanics, renormalization, critical-phenomena

I'm currently exploring several concepts related to universality classes, phase transitions, and critical phenomena. My questions revolve around the comprehensiveness of universality classes, the classification of systems with multiple transition points, and the identification of new universality classes based on critical exponents. I would appreciate insights on the following:

**Exhaustiveness of Universality Classes:** Are universality classes considered exhaustive in physics? Is there still room for discovering new universality classes, or does the current theoretical framework cover all possible scenarios? I'm interested in whether unexplored phenomena might exist that do not fit into existing categories.

**Universality Classes for Systems with Multiple Transition Points**: For systems exhibiting multiple transition points, each obeying scaling laws with associated critical exponents, is there an established universality class? If not, why might this be the case, and could there potentially be a universality class developed for such systems?

**Identification of New Universality Classes Based on Critical Exponents**: If the critical exponents of a system (be it with single or multiple transition points) are found and they do not match any known universality class, can one declare it as a new type of universality class directly? What steps or criteria must be met before defining it as such? (Is it necessary for all critical exponents to be identifiable for a system to be classified under a universality class? If we determine the presence of some critical exponents but find others to be non-existent or undefined, does this still suffice to categorize/declare the system as belonging to a specific universality class?)

Any guidance, references, or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Concerning your first point: definitevely no for non equilibrium systems since we don't have as much restriction as for equilibrium ones. We are finding a lot of new universality classes (for example by relaxing the condition of analytically of the (effective/non-equilibrium) free energy)

Comment: What about equlibrium ones? Are they restricted?

Comment: For equilibrium classical and non topological phase transition, the universality classes are restricted by symetry laws and analyticity of the free energy. Nonetheless, if you have a finite amount of symetries you have an infinite amount of terms that respect these symetries. Alrothough, fortunately, under the renormalization group, most of them are irrelevant and you end up with a finite number of terms in your free energy that mist respect some give symetries that are in finite number. So one could day that for equilibrium classical phase, we have probably found every classes.

Comment: I agree that we've found a large number of symmetries in equilibrium, but we're still finding new / exotic generalized symmetries, higher-form symmetries, and combinations of symmetries and kinetic constraints that have new universal properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer what I can:

1. The list of universality classes presently known is **not remotely exhaustive**. New universality classes (in and out of equilibrium) are found all the time! Currently, the best place to look for new universality classes are in topological phases of matter, constrained systems (e.g., fractons and fragmentation), and classical and quantum systems out of equilibrium (in the presence of periodic or quasiperiodic drives, with time-dependent fields, in the presence of a dissipative bath), *active* systems (e.g., flocks of birds and tumbling bacteria, which are open classical systems), and complex systems like classical spin glasses and piles of sand. These systems are all hard to study, so there are many open directions.
2. I'll assume you mean "phase transitions," thermal or otherwise. Basically, one expects a notion of universality / a universality class for each phase and all critical points or lines. A phase diagram, which exists in "parameter space," is nicely understood in terms of coarse graining via Wilson's renormalization group (RG). See Kardar's *[Statistical Physics of Fields](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-334-statistical-mechanics-ii-statistical-physics-of-fields-spring-2014/)* or notes from [David Tong](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/sft.html) or [John McGreevy](https://mcgreevy.physics.ucsd.edu/f18/2018F-217-lectures.pdf). All parameter values in a given phase "flow" under the RG toward the "fixed point" that describes the "universal" properties shared by all points in the phase. Distinct phases are separated by critical points or lines, which have correlations on all length scales and other "universal" properties. Many known models have multiple transitions / phases.
3. If *any* of the values of the universal / critical exponents are new, then yeah you have a new universality class! If a new value of *any* universal / critical exponent is (correctly) identified, you have found a new universality class.  The "critical" exponents apply to the critical points / lines separating phases, and it's possible to find new types of critical points with new exponents. I am not aware of a situation where certain exponents aren't defined, but I am aware of many where they are much harder to extract (e.g., in the absence of continuous symmetries). Do you have a particular example where certain critical exponents aren't defined? Anyway, while you should know the values of all exponents to understand the universality class / critical point (i.e., for the purposes of classification / experimental identification), you can safely say that a new class exists if you've found a new value of an exponent.

I also suggest these [other notes](https://mcgreevy.physics.ucsd.edu/s21/2021-211C-lectures.pdf) by McGreevy. I think the book by Kardar is a fantastic introduction, but the other links I've provided are free :).

Comment: I have one last question and I really appreciate it if you can answer. Let's say in my system I've found that some parameters like susceptiblity and fisher exponent are indeed scale invariant and I'm able to identify them. Even if I can't identify other critical exponents(let's say either it's not theoretically or practically not possible), can I still claim a universality class for it? Can you also include this in your answer?

Comment: If the values of the exponents you *can* compute are new, then yeah, you can claim a new universality class. But it might not be considered "accepted" / "established" until the other exponents are understood, or it can be shown that they aren't defined. Because then you've understood the *phase*. I've updated my third point to reflect this.